# Add image in first column in list view C#

Tags: c#

I have 7 column in my list view then i want to add image in first column. How I can solve this problem.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

- Add a `ImageList` control to your form.
- Assign that `ImageList` to the `ListView` (there are properties for small/big icons)
- Add your images to the `ImageList` (can happen dynamically)
- Add the correct index to the `ListViewItem`'s constructor (or set the icon later on).